# Can a shared library (.so) file built for linux be included/linked and used in an Android application?

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk

I am working on a project in which I need to include [NGSpice](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/) simulation library in an Android application and of course be able to use it.

I tried including the NGSpice windows DLL in my android application using SWIG and Android NDK, but it turned out that it is not even possible, so now I started to think about building NGSpice as a [shared library for linux](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/shared.html).

And now my question is, can I use the linux shared library for NGSpice as it is in my Android application, or does it need to built differently somehow to work on my Android application.

Thanks.

Comment: It needs to be build for Android...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.  Android typically has two key differences from a traditional linux:

1) It uses the Bionic C library and dynamic linker, instead of a more traditional set such as glibc.

2) Android is typically run on an ARM or 32-bit x86 processor (or in rare cases MIPS), while your desktop Linux library might be either 64-bit or 32-bit x86 code.

If you build a .so compatible with the architecture of the machine and with bionic's system library functions and dynamic linker, then it should be workable.

Alternatively, if you have something for a compatible architecture but the wrong libc, it may be possible to write your own loader to get it into memory in working form on a secured device, or on a rooted device it is possible to run a more traditional linux userspace (typically Debian derived) in a chroot.  But neither of these would be easy to integrate into an Android application - for the latter you'd almost definitely have to pass work over via interprocess communication, and that might prove easier in the former case as well.

**Your only really endorsed solution is to rebuild the library from source, using either the ndk build system, or an ndk-generated "stand alone toolchain" and the library's current build system.**