# Would Xamarin help in porting win32 DLL to android shared library?

Tags: android, android-ndk, xamarin

I am working on a project in which I need to include NGSpice simulation library in an Android application and of course be able to use it.

I need to port the [NGSpice](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/shared.html) windows DLL to my android application, how far would [xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) help me in this task? its a win32 dll, its not .Net based dll, please have a look at [NGSpice](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/shared.html) link

Thanks.

Comment: I think, as long as the compile target is arm it should work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a shared library (.so) file built for linux be included/linked and used in an Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280391/can-a-shared-library-so-file-built-for-linux-be-included-linked-and-used-in-a)

Comment: The windows dll will not work. Since android is arm platform you need to compile the source for arm.

Comment: I am asking about using xamarin, would it be the solution? my project has thousands of files scattered into folders

Comment: No, your problem has nothing to do with Xamarin.  Xamarin helps a lot if you have existing .Net managed code (F#, C#, etc), but doesn't do anything special for C/C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible using the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Since reading through all the docs can be somewhat overwhelming at first, I'll give you a quick tour.

1. Install the NDK
2. Create a folder named **jni** inside your project directory
3. Inside that folder create a subfolder **lib** and copy the required source files of your library to that folder
4. Inside the **jni** folder create two files, wrapper.c and wrapper.h. These files should contain high level wrappers around your native library suitable for binding from the C# side using DllImport
5. Inside the **jni** folder create a file named **Android.mk**
6. Inside the **jni** folder create a file named **Application.mk**
7. run **ndk-build**
8. Once ndk-build completes successfully create subfolder **lib** inside your C# project directory and copy the generated native libraries including their surrounding folder to **lib**. Your folder structure should look like this: **<project>** -> **libs** -> **armeabi** and **x86** (both folders contain an architure specific .so file). By establishing this folder structure, we ensure that MonoDroid will automatically load the matching library for the current runtime architecture.
9. Create new C# Class file **Foo.cs** inside your C# project. This class implements the binding glue between your native library wrapper and the C# world.
10. Profit!

**Android.mk:**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libFoo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := wrapper.c lib/source1.c lib/sourcen.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Note:** lib/source1.c and lib/sourcen.c need to be substituted by the names of your actually library source files.

**Application.mk:**

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
```

This line tells ndk-build which architectures you wish to support. x86 is for the Intel Android HAXM Simulator.

**wrapper.h:**

```
#pragma once

typedef struct _InternalState
{
    FILE *m_pFile;
} InternalState;

//////////////////////
// Public API

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif /* __cplusplus */

InternalState *FooCreate(int foo);
void FooDoStuff(InternalState *pState);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */
```

**wrapper.c:**

```
//////////////////////
// Public API

InternalState *FooCreate(int foo)
{
  // Initialize actual library here
  // return state if necessary
}

void FooDoStuff(InternalState *pState)
{
  // Call actual library here
}
```

**Foo.cs:**

```
public class Foo :
  IDisposable
{
  private IntPtr handle;
  private bool disposed;

  private Foo(IntPtr handle)
  {
    this.handle = handle;
  }

  ~Foo()
  {
    Dispose(false);
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  public void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    disposed = true;

    Close();
  }

  #region Native Imports

  [DllImport("libFoo")]
  private static extern IntPtr FooCreate(int seed);
  [DllImport("libFoo")]
  private static extern void FooDoStuff(IntPtr pHandle);

  #endregion

  private void VerifyHandle()
  {
    if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Handle not initialized");
  }

  #region Public API

  public static Foo FromSeed(int seed)
  {
    IntPtr handle = FooCreate(seed);
    if(handle == IntPtr.Zero)
      throw new System.Exception("Failed to create native object");

    return new Foo(handle);
  }

  public void DoStuff()
  {
    VerifyHandle();

    FooDoStuff(handle);
  }

  #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am asking about xamarin tool, I don't want to get into the process of fixing errors .. especially those that are related to windows ..

Comment: There's no tool for this.

Comment: Actually, I was asking about this http://xamarin.com/ , would it really solve my problem?

Comment: According to the NGSpice documentation, the library is cross platform. So the steps outlined in my post should be applicable. But you don't really need MonoDroid unless you want to consume that library in C# _on_ Android.